# Looping Hash Map does not return correct Key

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hash map type array list:

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

It has some IDs and Names like this:

[image]

This is the code that is used to loop through:

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : mylist)
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
        if(entry.getValue().contains(typedText)){
            map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map1.put("id", entry.getKey());
            map1.put("name",  entry.getValue());
            mylist1.add(map1);
        }
```

Problem is that in this line:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
```

`map.entrySet()` shows correct ID and the Name like this:

[image]

But only Name is available with 'entry':

[image]

`entry.getKey()` always returns the text 'name' which is the key and `entry.getValue()` returns 'Katie Bailey' which is the value.

My question is why am I not getting the key with entry.getKey()? Why do I always get 'name' as the key with each iteration?

Comment: Please pay more attention to your formatting in future - and remember that Stack Overflow doesn't work well with tabs; use spaces instead when formatting code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you're getting confused by the debugger's visualization of the map. When it's showing this:

```
{id=2990511, name=Katie Bailey}
```

that's showing that your map has two entries - one with a key of `id` and a value of `"2990511"`, and one with a key of `name` and a value of `"Katie Bailey"`.

You're then looping over all those entries, and if the value matches you're adding two entries into a second map: one entry with the key `id` and a value which is the key of **the entry you're looking at**, and a second entry with the key `name` and a value which is the value of the entry you're looking at. You're not using the whole of the original map - you're *just* using that single entry.

So if you match on the entry of `name=Katie Bailey` you end up with a new map containing two entries:

```
{id=name, name=Katie Bailey}
```

It's not really clear what you were expecting, but the results you've shown make perfect sense with your code.

I suspect you *actually* want something like:

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : mylist) {
    String name = map.get("name");
    if (name.contains(typedText)) {
       // Create a copy of the whole map
       mylist1.add(new HashMap<String, String>(map));
    }
}
```

If you've got fixed keys though, you should at least consider creating a type to encapsulate the data - e.g. a `Person` class with `getName()` and `getId()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is map only takes unique values for the key, therefore, if a key exists in the map, it cannot be re-inserted in the map, that results in you getting the first matching value.

For that matter you have to provide different keys to be substituted. Using a string such as "id" or "name" for the key means that key does not change, and so does the value.

Refer to [Java HashMap API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)